# : data must be a data frame, or other object coercible by fortify(), not an S3 object with class gg/ggplot

Tags: r

I'm getting the error: Error: data must be a data frame, or other object coercible by fortify(), not an S3 object with class gg/ggplot

```
emp <- read.csv("employee_data.csv")
emp = as.tibble(emp)

view(emp)
str(emp)
head(emp)

empd = ggplot(emp)
empd

empd$title = factor(empd$title)
empd$salary = factor(empd$salary)
empd$emp_no = factor(empd$emp_no)

//Error is happening with this line
empd = ggplot(empd, aes(x=salary)) + 
 empd + geom_histogram(binwidth=5)
```

Comment: Please share your data with `dput`

Comment: Drop the `+` after the 1st line. `empd = ggplot(empd, aes(x=salary))` and `empd + geom_histogram(binwidth=5)` should be separate lines.

Comment: I think you mean `empd = emp` instead of `empd = ggplot(emp)`; the immediately following lines look like they're meant to update a data frame, but by putting `emp` into `ggplot` you're converting it into a plot object.

Answer (score 0):

Try only

```
ggplot(emp, aes(x=salary)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=5)
```

and be careful to not overwrite your data.frame